# Are there tools or algorithms to detect organic molecules from 3D crystal structures?

Tags: computational-chemistry, crystal-structure, materials, cheminformatics, crystallography

The task I'm thinking of is to detect entire molecules from structures, such as in a crystallographic information file (CIF) or from the XYZ file generated in a molecular dynamics simulation. Crystallography itself doesn't help identify the molecular identity (such as represented in IUPAC name or as a SMILES string), but requires human interpretation or computational modelling.

Three example use cases:

1. Identify the spatial orientation of all the moieties of molecule X in a molecular crystal of X.
2. Identify locations of solvent molecules trapped in crystals
3. Identify parts of a molecule that has multiple copies in the crystal.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm/software?

Comment: If you can get the structure why would you not know the name beforehand?

Comment: I'm looking for part of a structure that is still molecular. In other scenarios, if you have multiple copies of the same molecule, their spatial orientation (such as packing) would be interesting to understand. Neither of these would be possible without identifying the molecular entity in 3D (e.g. as a grouping)

Comment: Its not clear what you want as the cif/sdf/pdb etc. data (obtained usually from x-ray crystallography) contains all the information, i.e. xyz coords and connection table to work out where the bonds are,  so you can draw the molecule at a pinch by hand from the connection table. If you don't have a connection table you can use known bond lengths and atom positions to work one out by writing some simple code.

Comment: I updated the questions with use cases, perhaps it will explain things better

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think that helps much. Perhaps if you have an example CIF in which you think this is necessary? The space group, for example will give you all the symmetric copies and orientations of a molecule in the unit cell. Finding a solvent isn’t very hard either, because you can look through the bonded components to find solvents or co-crystals.

Comment: Load the file into a 3D browser like JSmol. It will show bonds where they make sense, allowing you to distinguish between distinct molecules in the structure. Some cases might be more complex and you would need to know what is considered a molecule in that context.

Comment: Indeed, pretty much any program that handles CIF .. CCDC Mercury, JSmol, etc.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, the problem is not with one or two CIFs, which can definitely be solved using these classic approaches you mentioned. I would need to do the same for hundreds to thousands of structures, which will not be possible without an algorithm. Perhaps defining a bond length constraint then gradually iterate over the atomic combinations can work.

Comment: @QGent - I think you misunderstand. Basically anything that handles a CIF can do what you describe. Most (e.g. Open Babel, CCDC Python interface) can be scripted to automate the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has a few parts, but multiple solutions. Let's start with "XYZ from molecular dynamics"

```
3
XYZ file generated by Avogadro.
O     -2.86063    1.04260   -0.00000
H     -2.52287    1.38117    0.82085
H     -3.53528    0.39764    0.17713
```

This is trivial. Open Babel will read this, perceive the bonds through inter-atomic distances, and generate water. Most programs do this. (RDKit should use the [xyz2mol](https://github.com/jensengroup/xyz2mol) package.)

Problems come when you want to perceive bond orders .. because it's a non-trivial task. Both Open Babel and `xyz2mol` have algorithms..

You ask about solvent molecules. Again, both Open Babel and RDKit have methods to find and/or remove fragments, e.g. ["An open source chemical structure curation pipeline using RDKit"](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-020-00456-1)

Then you ask about multiple copies (e.g., in a CIF)

Here's part of an [aspirin entry in the COD](http://crystallography.net/cod/1515581.html):

```
O1 O 0.62354(11) 0.1419(2) 0.61266(11) 0.0203(3) Uani 1 1 d .
H1 H 0.577(2) 0.025(5) 0.602(2) 0.060(8) Uiso 1 1 d .
O2 O 0.50970(11) 0.1879(2) 0.40933(11) 0.0212(3) Uani 1 1 d .
O3 O 0.78878(10) 0.41876(19) 0.72945(10) 0.0171(3) Uani 1 1 d .
O4 O 0.90669(11) 0.2189(2) 0.66325(11) 0.0215(3) Uani 1 1 d .
C1 C 0.65418(15) 0.4419(3) 0.50750(16) 0.0154(4) Uani 1 1 d .
C2 C 0.74806(15) 0.5203(3) 0.61181(16) 0.0162(4) Uani 1 1 d .
C3 C 0.80069(16) 0.7061(3) 0.60519(17) 0.0196(4) Uani 1 1 d .
H3 H 0.8632 0.7580 0.6776 0.024 Uiso 1 1 calc R
C4 C 0.76267(16) 0.8174(3) 0.49303(18) 0.0215(4) Uani 1 1 d .
H4 H 0.7997 0.9449 0.4882 0.026 Uiso 1 1 calc R
C5 C 0.67053(16) 0.7425(3) 0.38781(17) 0.0195(4) Uani 1 1 d .
H5 H 0.6444 0.8182 0.3106 0.023 Uiso 1 1 calc R
C6 C 0.61699(15) 0.5578(3) 0.39559(16) 0.0173(4) Uani 1 1 d .
H6 H 0.5534 0.5081 0.3233 0.021 Uiso 1 1 calc R
C7 C 0.59016(15) 0.2458(3) 0.50601(15) 0.0151(4) Uani 1 1 d .
C8 C 0.86823(15) 0.2623(3) 0.74362(16) 0.0166(4) Uani 1 1 d .
C9 C 0.89840(17) 0.1611(3) 0.86922(17) 0.0249(5) Uani 1 1 d .
H7 H 0.9545 0.0480 0.8770 0.037 Uiso 1 1 calc R
H8 H 0.8259 0.1059 0.8769 0.037 Uiso 1 1 calc R
H9 H 0.9347 0.2625 0.9366 0.037 Uiso 1 1 calc R
```

That's it. That's the connected component for an aspirin molecule. If there were solvent, it would be a disconnected fragment if you, e.g. convert to SDF or SMILES.

How do you know the symmetric copies? It's in the CIF as defined by the space group.

```
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
'x, y, z'
'-x, y+1/2, -z+1/2'
'-x, -y, -z'
'x, -y-1/2, z-1/2'
```

This gives you the transforms (in fractional coordinates) for all the symmetric copies. Some may be duplicates. But if you have a point $(x,y,z)$ there's a symmetric copy at $(-x, y + 0.5, -z + 0.5)$, etc. In other words this space group could have 4 copies of aspirin per unit cell.

[image: filled unit cell of aspirin]

You mention automation, which sounds like you want to write a script. Maybe that's in Open Babel. Maybe you use CCDC Python or ASE or pymatgen. There are likely other packages for handling `CIF` files. I don't know what precise features you want. But they should all find connected components. Once you've built the script to process one, adding an outer loop in Python to handle multiple files is fairly easy, e.g.:

```
for filename in glob.iglob("*.cif"):
    # do something
```

Comment: In terms of implementation questions, I would generally suggest that the https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/ is better suited.